# Looping row numbers from one dataframe to create new data using logical operations in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to extract a dataframe that shows **how many years** it takes for *NInd* variable (*dataset p1*) to recover due to some culling happening, which is showed in *dataframe e1*.

I have the following datasets (mine are much bigger, but just to give you something to play with):

```
# Dataset 1
Batch <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Rep <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Year <- c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
RepSeason <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
PatchID <- c(17,25,19,16,21,24,23,20,18,33)
Species <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Selected <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Nculled <- c(811,4068,1755,449,1195,1711,619,4332,457,5883)

e1 <- data.frame(Batch,Rep,Year,RepSeason,PatchID,Species,Selected,Nculled)

# Dataset 2
Batch <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Rep <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Year <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
RepSeason <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
PatchID <- c(17,25,19,16,21,24,23,20,18,33,17,25,19,16,21,24,23,20,18,33,17,25,19,16,21,24,23,20,18,33)
Ncells <- c(6,5,6,4,4,5,6,5,5,5,6,5,6,4,4,5,6,7,3,5,4,4,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,4)
Species <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
NInd <- c(656,656,262,350,175,218,919,218,984,875,700,190,93,127,52,54,292,12,43,68,308,1000,98,29,656,656,262,350,175,300)

p1 <- data.frame(Batch, Rep, Year, RepSeason, PatchID, Ncells, Species, NInd)
```

The dataset called *e1* shows only those year where some culled happened to the population on specific *PatchID*.

I have created the following script that basically use each row from *e1* to create a *Recovery number*. Maybe there is an easier way to get to the end, but this is the one I managed to get...
When you run this, you are working on ONE row of *e1*, so we focus on the first *PatchID* encounter and then do some calculation to match that up with *p1*, and finally I get a number named *Recovery*.

Now, the thing is my dataframe has 50,000 rows, so doing this over and over looks quite tedious. So, that's where I thought a loop may be useful. But have tried and no luck on how to make it work at all...

```
#here is where I would like the loop
e2 <- e1[1,] # Trial for one row only # but the idea is having here a loop that keep doing of comes next for each row

e3 <- e2 %>% 
  select(1,2,4,5)

p2 <- p1[,c(1,2,4,5,3,6,7,8)] # Re-order 

row2 <- which(apply(p2, 1, function(x) return(all(x == e3))))

p3 <- p1 %>% 
  slice(row2) # all years with that particular patch in that particular Batch

#How many times was this patch cull during this replicate?
e4 <- e2[,c(1,2,4,5,3,6,7,8)]

e4 <- e4 %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4)

c_batch <- e1[,c(1,2,4,5,3,6,7,8)]

row <- which(apply(c_batch, 1, function(x) return(all(x == e4))))

c4 <- c_batch %>% 
  slice(row)

# Number of year to recover to 95% that had before culled
c5 <- c4[1,] # extract the first time was culled
c5 <- c5 %>% 
  select(1:5)


row3 <- which(apply(p2, 1, function(x) return(all(x == c5))))

Before <- p2 %>% 
  slice(row3)

NInd <- Before[,8] # Before culling number of individuals
Year2 <- Before[,5] # Year number where first culling happened (that actually the number corresponds to individuals before culling, as the Pop file is developed during reproduction, while Cull file is developed after!)
Percent <- (95*NInd)/100 # 95% recovery we want to achieve would correspond to having 95% of NInd BEFORE culled happened (Year2)

After <- p3 %>% 
  filter(NInd >= Percent & Year > Year2) # Look rows that match number of ind and Year

After2 <- After[1,] # we just want the first year where the recovery was successfully achieved

Recovery <- After2$Year - Before$Year
# no. of years to reach 95% of the population immediately before the cull
```

I reckon that the end would have to change somehow to to tell R that we are creating a dataframe with the Recovery, something like:

```
Batch <- c(1,1,2,2)
Rep <- c(0,0,0,0)
PatchID <- c(17,25,30,12)
Recovery <- c(1,2,1,5)

Final <- data.frame(Batch, Rep, PatchID, Recovery)
```

Would that be possible? OR this is just too mess-up and I may should try a different way?

Comment: What libraries did you use? I can't reproduce your example. Also, it would be even more helpful if you showed an example of your desired output. That way I won't need to install every library you've used if they are not necessary.

Comment: There are no Batch 1, and PatchID numbers 30 and 12 in your data set.

Comment: In the code, `p2` and `p3` are not defined so this is not currently reproducible. I am having trouble understanding the desired output as well. Maybe just post the 'solution' to the example dataset (worked out by hand) so we can better help to provide a code version.

Comment: Is it possible to have a PatchID culled more than once in your data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following solve the problem correectly?

I have first added a unique ID to your data.frames to allow matching of the cull and population files (this saves most of you complicated look-up code):

```
# Add a unique ID for the patch/replicate etc. (as done in the example code)
e1$RepID = paste(e1$Batch, e1$Rep, e1$RepSeason, e1$PatchID, sep = ":")
p1$RepID = paste(p1$Batch, p1$Rep, p1$RepSeason, p1$PatchID, sep = ":")
```

If you want a quick overview of the number of times each patch was culled, the new `RepID` makes this easy:

```
# How many times was each patch culled?
table(p1$RepID)
```

Then you want a loop to check the recovery time after each cull.
My solutions uses an `sapply` loop (which also retains the RepIDs so you can match to other metadata later):

```
sapply(unique(e1$RepID), function(rep_id){
    all_cull_events = e1[e1$RepID == rep_id, , drop = F]
    first_year = order(all_cull_events$Year)[1] # The first cull year (assuming data might not be in temporal order)
    first_cull_event = all_cull_events[first_year, ] # The row corresponding to the first cull event 

    population_counts = p1[p1$RepID == first_cull_event$RepID, ] # The population counts for this plot/replicate
    population_counts = population_counts[order(population_counts$Year), ] # Order by year (assuming data might not be in temporal order)
    pop_at_first_cull_event = population_counts[population_counts$Year == first_cull_event$Year, "NInd"]
    population_counts_after_cull = population_counts[population_counts$Year > first_cull_event$Year, , drop = F]
    years_to_recovery = which(population_counts_after_cull$NInd >= (pop_at_first_cull_event * .95))[1] # First year to pass 95% threshold
    return(years_to_recovery)
})
```

```
2:0:0:17 2:0:0:25 2:0:0:19 2:0:0:16 2:0:0:21 2:0:0:24 2:0:0:23 2:0:0:20 2:0:0:18 2:0:0:33 
       1        2        1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

(The output contains some NAs because the first cull year was outside the range of population counts in the data you gave us)

Please check this against your expected output though. There were some aspects of the question and example code that were not clear (see comments).